# macOS 10.13.4 not installed and disappeared from AppStore

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra

I started to update my MBP (2013) to macOS 10.13.4 using the AppStore.

After installation and login, I got a notification that some things didn't get install.

I opened the AppStore, macOS 10.13.4 is not available anymore to download, neither it is in the Installed section.

I checked also "About This Mac", my version is still 10.13.3

No, I never installed any Betas or GM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by booting in Safe Mode and install macOS 10.13.4 from there.

Answer (score 0):

Along with booting into Safe Mode, you could try to manually install the macOS 10.13.4 update. This will download an installer that should install macOS 10.13.4 without using the Mac App Store.

Download the update here — [Download macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1959?locale=en_US)